# Xcode:Singleton implementation error: " Redefinition of class"

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, compiler-errors

I'm trying to implement C++ singleton inside of Xcode project but I'm getting this error:

```
Redefinition of class
```

Here is my code (.hpp file):

```
#ifndef DoingSomething_hpp
#define DoingSomething_hpp
#include <stdio.h>
#endif /* DoingSomething_hpp */

class DoingSomething {

public:
    static DoingSomething *instance(); 
};
```

This is my .cpp file:

```
#include "DoingSomething.hpp"
class DoingSomething
{
    static DoingSomething *shareInstance;
public:
    int doSomething()
    {
        /*
         */
        return 6;
    }

    static DoingSomething *instance()
    {
        if (!shareInstance)
            shareInstance = new DoingSomething;
        return shareInstance;
    }
};
```

On this line (on my cpp file)

```
class DoingSomething
```

I'm getting this error:

Redefinition of "DoingSomething".

[image]

Any of you knows what I doing wrong or how can fix this error?
I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: The entire `class` declaration in the .cpp file doesn't belong there. Only the *implementation* goes there. The error is self-explanatory. You already defined what `DoingSomething` looks like in the header. There are no do-overs in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your class twice in the same translation unit `DoingSomething.cpp`, i.e. once in the header file you include and again in the `cpp`-file itself.
Put the class declaration in the header file, and the implementation in the `.cpp`-file:

**Header, i.e. DoingSomething.hpp**

```
#ifndef DoingSomething_hpp
#define DoingSomething_hpp
#include <stdio.h>

class DoingSomething {

public:
    int doSomething();
    static DoingSomething *instance(); 
};

#endif /* DoingSomething_hpp */
```

**Implementation, i.e. DoingSomething.cpp**

```
#include "DoingSomething.hpp"

int DoingSomething ::doSomething() {
    return 6;
}

DoingSomething *DoingSomething::instance() {
    if (!shareInstance)
        shareInstance = new DoingSomething;
    return shareInstance;
}
```